# calling getModule inside init leads to infinite loop

Tags: yii

Calling getModule inside init() function in Module class leads to infinite loop. This is because getModule itself calls init()

Version : yii 1.1.14

Is this by design that each call of getModule() leads to calling of init () ?

It has some of these side effects as above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you read http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModule#getModule-detail you'll see that on each `getModule()` call a new instance is loaded.

But I guess the infinite loop only occurs when you call the same module in the init function. You would never have to do that, because `$this` will contain the current module in the init of a module class.

Comment: but there can be circular dependency between module A and Module B and so module A calls getModule(B) in A::init() and module B calls getModule(A) in B::init()

Comment: Very true. Just have to be careful about how you make your calls I guess ;)